# Dynamic naming of Objects

Tags: java, class, object

I am doing a project for a class and I am required to create a program where you can input "Employee data" such as name, employee number, department, and position into the program and then have the program read that information back out to you.

All of this is to be done through the console to provide input for the names.

Catch is I don't know how many employees they are going to throw at my program.  I need a way to dynamically create objects from my "Employee" class and name them.

Does anyone have any suggestions.  Unfortunately I don't have any code to write because I am at a loss of where to begin. I have created my employee class with methods that can set each of the parameters, but again, the issue is creating the class from the console in the first place.

Comment: You can't dynamically 'name' variables, and neither do you need to. The 'dynamic parts' is what you have to store in it's instance variables.
If you don't know how many you'll have, use a List, not an array, to store them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to name the objects dynamically (actually, you probabely don't need a reference to the object at all). Just store the created objects in a collection.

Comment: That's my question. How do I create the objects in the first place in such a way that the object name is predictable.

Comment: Its not possible (and also not needed in this case). What is predictable is the index of the object in the e.g. ArrayList in which you put them

Comment: Okay. I'll play around and see if I can figure it out. If I have some code to show soon I will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ArrayList, check the implementation:

Declare and initalize variable:

```
ArrayList<Employee> empArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Add employee to the array:

```
empArray.add(aEmployee);
```

Retrive employee from array:

```
empArray.get(0);
```

Here you have more documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

- Create an employee object with feilds like name, department, position etc.
- Then create a HashSet or ArrayList of these objects
- Then write code that reads in the input
- After each complete employee is read, create an employee object with the input
- Add the employee object to the List or Set.

When all the employee data is read in, loop through your List or Set and print out the employee objects.

edit: Responding to your comment here, since comments cannot be formatted:

Can you set up a ListArray of Strings? Its like this:

```
List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Just like that, you make a ListArray of your employee object:

```
List<Employee> employeeList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

You create the List once, and you create Employee objects for each employee. You create a new Employee object with new Employee(). Assuming you have written the code for the Employee object with getters and setters, its something like this:

```
Employee employee;

// ... in a loop, reading all the input data..
employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("Reggie");
employeeList.add(employee);
//... end your loop here....
```

Once you have created and added all the employees, you just loop through the list with a for loop:

```
for(Employee emp:employeeList) {
    System.out.println(emp.getName());
}
```

Comment: I can create the listarray and set up variables to hold that information. However, I don't know how to then create a new object (either in the array or out) and then retrieve that later.